# How did multiplying the numerator and denominator by the same fraction really simplified this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, rational-functions

The original equation was without the added $\frac{2x-1}{2x-1}$. I don't understand how it simplified the equation. How did we get from step 2 to step 3, where all fractions within fractions vanished?

[image: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/InverseFunctions_files/eq0076LP.gif]

Comment: That's basically $a(\frac{b}{a}+c)=b + a c\,$.

Comment: Let $2x - 1 = M$ then $(2x-1)(2\frac {4+5x}{2x-1} -5) = M(2\frac{4+5x}{M} - 5) = M*2\frac{4+5x}M - 5M = 2(4+5x) - 5M = 2(4+5x) -5(2x-1)$.  Same for the top.

Answer (score 4):

They just distributed the $2x-1$ on the top and did the same to the bottom. This was helpful because we had fractions within fractions and in this particular case, eliminating them simplifies things a lot.

In the numerator: $$(2x-1)\cdot \left(\dfrac{4+5x}{2x-1}+4\right)=(2x-1)\cdot\left(\dfrac{4+5x}{2x-1}\right)+(2x-1)\cdot 4$$
$$=4+5x+8x-4=13x$$
In the denominator: $$(2x-1)\cdot\left(2\left(\dfrac{4+5x}{2x-1}\right)-5\right)=(2x-1)\cdot 2\left(\dfrac{4+5x}{2x-1}\right)-(2x-1)\cdot 5$$
$$=2(4+5x)-(10x-5)=8+10x-10x+5=13$$
and the other simplifications follow.